# Problem(s) with Linked List

Tags: c, linked-list

Just started with creating a Linked List in C. Getting runtime error in the code for returnLastNode. How do I know? Runs fine when it's commented out.

**Question#1** What am I doing wrong?

Code for my `returnLastNode` function

```
struct Node* returnLastNode(struct LinkedList *ll) {
    struct Node *n = ll->first;
    struct Node *result;
    while(1) {
        if(n->next == NULL) {
            result = n;
            break;
        } else {
            n = n->next;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Definition of `struct`s used.

```
struct Node {
    int val;
    struct Node *next;
};

struct LinkedList {
    struct Node *first;
};
```

`LinkedList.h` here, if needed/interested.

https://github.com/MoonStruckHorrors/LinkedListC/blob/master/LinkedList.h

**Question #2** How a newbie should debug runtime errors?

Also, any other suggestions are appreciated. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never check if `n` is `NULL` before dereferencing it. This means your code will crash when used on an empty list. Also you can get rid of the variable `result` and just `return n;` in the `if (n->next == NULL)` part. So a better version of your code might look like this:

```
struct Node* returnLastNode(struct LinkedList *ll) {
    struct Node *n = ll->first;

    // checking if n is NULL here
    while(n) {
        if(n->next == NULL)
             return n;

        n = n->next;
    }

    return NULL; // n was NULL immediately so there is no end node
}
```

As for debugging runtime errors, you can use `printf` to check what data is for simple things, and for more complex things you can use a debugger like [gdb](http://www.gnu.org/s/gdb/) (or sometimes IDEs (such as Visual Studio) come with integrated debuggers).

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I was checking for an empty list in the my insert function(which uses `returnLastNode` only when the linked list is  non-empty). But even though I checked for empty lists there, I forgot to initialize a Node for `first` & therefore, was operating on a NULL.

Answer (score 2):

```
struct Node* returnLastNode(struct LinkedList *ll) {
    struct Node *n = ll->first;
    struct Node *result = n;
    while(n != NULL)
    {
       result = n;
       n = n -> next;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Would be better. As to debugging it is just practice.

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef struct Node_t {
   int val;
   struct Node *next;
}Node;

typedef struct LinkedList_t {
   struct Node *first;
}LinkedList;
```

Call it by :

```
      returnLastNode(SomeLinkedList.first);

Node* returnLastNode(Node *p) {
   while (p && p->next) p=p->next;
   return p;
}
```

Would be way better... Debugging ability is something you gain with time, the only way to boost it is by sitting down next to some one who knows to debug better then you and learn from him, a good way perhaps better yet way slower is to just debug like crazy and try to get better by yourself.
goodluck anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Gdb and Valgrind are pretty cool for debugging